# How to construct a link in JavaScript from captured innerHTML value?

Tags: javascript, html

suppose I have

```
    <a href="#" id="someid">findme</a>  (innertext can be whatever other than findme)
```

and I when click on 'findme' I want to redirect to page '/?q=findme'. (the value should be inserted afer /?q= to create a new link and page should redirect to that link.)
How to do that using javascript ?

Comment: Can you explain yourself better? perhaps giving a complete example

Comment: Why not set the href to be `/?q=findme`?

Comment: @Reyno Could be they do not have access to the code that produces the html...

Comment: @Reyno the value is not static. I am passing variable from django views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```js
const lnk = document.getElementById("someid"); // direct access
lnk.href = "/?q="+lnk.textContent; // set the href attribute
```

```html
<a href="#" id="someid">findme</a>
```

For more:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("#container a")] // get the html node list of anchors in the container
  .forEach(lnk => lnk.href = "/?q="+lnk.textContent); // set each of the hrefs
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="#" id="find">findme</a>
  <a href="#" id="goto">goto</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get inner text of the link and modify href attribute to point to your preferred location.

```js
const linkElement = document.getElementById('someid'); //get your link element by id
const innerValue = linkElement.innerText // get inner text value
linkElement.href = '/?q=' + innerValue // set href attribute
```

```html
<a href="#" id="someid">findme</a>
```

Comment: Post only code is not good answer. [Official Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @mplungjan my bad didn't double check. Thank you for spotting it up!

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks for guiding! tried to add some text explanation to make it better.